# How to create a Safe Module that allows custom logic in Paymaster?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I want to learn more about how to develop a Gnosis Safe module. Is Safe Core SDK built on top of the ERC 4337? I'd like to add some custom logic for the paymasters that can sponsor transactions for other users (here is where I want to add custom logic https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/blob/develop/contracts/core/BasePaymaster.sol#L26 )
How can I possibly do this and make it work with SAFE Core SDK?

Thank you!